# Solve $\arg\left (\frac{z-1}{1+i}\right) > \frac{ \pi}{2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, complex-numbers

I want to solve $$\arg \left(\frac{z-1}{1+i}\right) > \frac{ \pi}{2}$$

It should be fairly simple but I'm having difficulties.

What I tried:

\begin{align}\arg \left(\frac{z-1}{1+i}\right) &= \arg \left(\frac{(z-1)(1-i)}{2}\right) \\
&= \arg \left(\frac{z-iz -1 + i}{2}\right) \\
&= \arg \left(\frac{x+iy-ix+y-1+i}{2}\right) \\
&= \arg \left(\frac{x+y-1}{2} + i\frac{y-x+1}{2}\right) \\
&= \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\frac{y-x+1}{2}}{\frac{x+y-1}{2}}\right) \\
&= \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{-x+y+1}{x+y-1}\right)\end{align}

And so we must have that $$\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{-x+y+1}{x+y-1}\right) > \frac{\pi}{2}$$

But that is not possible... Where is my mistake and how do we solve this?

Comment: The problem is that the $tan^{-1}$ only works when $arg(z) \in (-\pi /2 , \pi /2)$. This is due to that being the principal branch of the function. But you are looking for complex numbers with arguments outside this branch and hence have to consider separate cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $z=x+iy$ where $x,y$ are real

$$\dfrac{x-1+iy}{1+i}=\dfrac{(x-1+iy)(1-i)}{1^2-i^2}=\dfrac{x-1+y+i(y+1-x)}2$$

Using the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2#Definition_and_computation) of atan$2$, we need  $$x-1+y<0\iff x<1-y;$$

$$y+1-x\ge0\iff x\le y+1$$